# element size using javascript - need to recalculate height as JSON data is filtered

Tags: javascript, json

```
var height = $("#mainbody").height();
$("#leftnav").css({"height":height});

$("#leftnav").css({"min-height":height,"padding-bottom":"15px","height":"auto"});

if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7){

    $("#leftnav").css({"height":height});


    $("#leftNavSearch ul li").each(function(){

        if($(this).height() < 20){

            $(this).css({"height":"20px"});

        }else{

            $(this).css({"height":"auto"});

        }

    });     

}else if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 7){

    $("#leftnav").css({"height":"auto"});

}
```

The above function calculates the height of the #mainbody and #leftnav matches it.

However, as you filter through the JSON data on the page, you end up with a lot of white space on the bottom.

What would be the best method to recalculate the height, as the filter links are selected?

Comment: JSON? Where? Remove `"padding-bottom":"15px"` if you want to get rid off the additional whitespace.

Comment: Please give us more information, or a jsfiddle. By filter do you mean that height of mainbody is reduced because you remove items / or hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should include [Ben Alman's great throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), which we will use limit the rate the resize function gets called.

Next thing we take your script and put it into a function

```
function resize_left_nav(){
    //YOUR SCRIPT GOES HERE        
}
```

After this we setup a custom event on the leftnav, which we will trigger to resize the column. We use throttle to limit the rate the resize_left_nav function gets called

```
$('#leftnav').bind('resize-column',function(){
    $.throttle(250, resize_left_nav);
});
```

We want to trigger this event on two occasions:

- on page load

  `$(function(){ $('#leftnav').trigger('resize-column'); });`
- when the item list gets updated. Just tirgger the event, when your filtering has completed.

To clean everything up a bit, we can wrap the whole code in an IIFE (Immediatly invoked function expression) like this:

```
(function(){
    function resize_left_nav(){ ... }

    $('#leftnav').bind( ... );

    $(function(){ ... });
})();
```